# Uber python API returns status 409 on ride request

Tags: python, uber-api

I'm following the instructions on the project page on [GitHub](https://github.com/uber/rides-python-sdk)
This is all running in **sandbox mode**

First I'm calling

```
estimate = client.estimate_ride(
  product_id=product_id,
  start_latitude=start_lat,
  start_longitude=start_long,
  end_latitude=end_lat,
  end_longitude=end_long,
  seat_count=seat_count
)
```

and getting back something like

```
{
"pickup_estimate": 2,
"trip": {
    "distance_estimate": 2.18,
    "distance_unit": "mile",
    "duration_estimate": 240
},
"fare": {
    "fare_id": "14f81e7421f0ae124c2e5a97d0b9cf975cbb84fdd2bf6fc8b7bb2f49fc6c6f8a",
    "value": 8.06,
    "display": "$8.06",
    "currency_code": "USD",
    "expires_at": 1489104865
}
```

}

Then I'm using the same product_id and the fare_id I got above (with a client object with the same credentials) running this

```
response = client.request_ride(
      product_id=product_id,
      start_latitude=start_lat,
      start_longitude=start_long,
      end_latitude=end_lat,
      end_longitude=end_long,
      seat_count=seat_count,
      fare_id=fare_id
  )
```

All I get is a `ClientError` exception with status 409.
Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue. I wasn't printing the error details correctly. As a result I saw just the error code and not the details.

To see the full error details I added:

```
    try:
      response = client.request_ride(
        product_id=product_id,
        start_latitude=start_lat,
        start_longitude=start_long,
        end_latitude=end_lat,
        end_longitude=end_long,
        seat_count=seat_count,
        fare_id=fare_id
     )
   except ClientError as error:
     self.response.out.write("error: {0}, {1}".format(error.errors, error.message))
```

Then I got this error that is very informative:
**409 missing_payment_method The rider must have at least one payment method on file to request a car. The rider must add a payment method**

Answer (score 3):

The 409 error is likely caused by you already having a trip in progress in the sandbox for this user. You can check with client.get_current_ride_details() and cancel the ongoing trip with client.cancel_current_ride().

Comment: client.get_current_ride_details() returns `ClientError: 404`.
Documentation says "If there is no trip in progress the endpoint will result in a 404 not found error"